# bind selected value to asp .net MVC ActionLink

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-4

Just Wondering can I assign my action link variable to the selected value of a drop down list or do I have to assign it with jquery.  I have the following example which works but just wondering if there is a better way.

Here is my view

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";}

@section head{
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        //begin populate the select list with A-Z
        for (var i = 0; i < 26; i++)
            $('<option value=' + String.fromCharCode((65 + i)) + '>' + String.fromCharCode((65 + i)) + '</option>').appendTo($('#select'));
        //end populate the select list with A-Z

        //code for clicking the filter link
        $('.link a').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var firstletter = $('#select').val(); //get the select value of the drop down

            var url = $(this).attr('href').replace("1", firstletter); //correct the url of the action link (Do I need to do this? or can I do it directly in the action link?)

            //call the controller Filter function
            $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
                $('#presidents').empty();  //empty out the ul

                //populate the ul with the filtered list
                $.each(data, function (index, president) {
                    $('<li>' + president + '</li>').appendTo($('#presidents'));
                });

            });
        });


    });

</script>

}
<h2>Presidents</h2>
<select id='select'>
<option value="all">all</option>
</select>
<li class="link">@Html.ActionLink("Filter", "Filter", new { firstletter = "1" })</li>
<ul id="presidents">
@foreach (var president in Model)
{   
    <li>@president</li>
}
</ul>
```

and here is my controller

```
namespace advancedviewtecniques.Controllers{
public class PresidentController : Controller
{
    private readonly string[] _presidents = {"Adams", "Arthur", "Buchanan", "Bush", 
                                             "Carter", "Cleveland", "Clinton", "Coolidge",
                                             "Eisenhower", "Fillmore", "Ford", "Garfield",
                                             "Grant","Harding", "Harrison", "Hayes", "Hoover",
                                              "Jackson", "Jefferson", "Johnson", "Kennedy",
                                              "Lincoln", "Madison", "McKinley", "Monroe",
                                              "Nixon", "Pierce",
                                               "Polk", "Reagan", "Roosevelt", "Taft",
                                                "Taylor", "Truman", "Tyler", 
                                                "Van Buren", "Washington", "Wilson"};

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(_presidents);
    }

    public ActionResult Filter(string firstletter)
    {
        if (firstletter != "all"){
        IEnumerable<string> filteredlist = _presidents.Where(p => p.StartsWith(firstletter));
        return Json(filteredlist, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        return Json(_presidents, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }} }
```

Comment: Pretty sure you have to do it with Jquery. If you are using Ajax actionlink you can use the OnBegin AjaxOption to simply append the value to the querystring.

Comment: I think your solution is better to change using JQuery.  Changing by ActionLink is made only in the razor view. I am not sure that we can change it dynamically.